# Simple slideout nav

Tags: nav

I'm not a big coder but I have my test html page built. What is the most simple way to code/add an html left slide navigation for mobile? I have seen so many solutions but having trouble getting it to work.

Comment: using straight CSS (no .js), using sidr, jquery.mmenu.

Comment: Is it possible to make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) of what you have so far? It will make answering your question much easier.

Comment: My latest code is here: artichokemedia.com/macaw/index.html. I have tried to implement the sidr.js as is described on http://designers.hubspot.com/blog/implement-hamburger-style-responsive-menu-into-hubspot-cos. You can see that I want the hamburger nav to appear on the left side @700 pixels wide. I think that the image of the city is actually covering up the nav and that the hamburger icon does not have the correct ID to trigger the .js.

Comment: Well for starters you have two JavaScript errors: `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` and `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined`. Are you sure you have the scripts pointed to the right path within your project? You can view these errors within the developer tools of your browser by hitting `f-12` while viewing your `index.html`

Comment: I see the errors. For '$ is not defined' is it trying to locate the path to the document 'jquery.sidr.min.js?. For the second error, it looks like the error is from within the js minified file?

Comment: Yes, I doubt it is a problem with the js minified file itself but rather it can't find the file within that location. Fixing the first error may solve the second one on its own.

Comment: I have pointed the $ location on line 12 to the js file:   $('js/jquery.sidr.min.js').ready(function() {  but it still throws the same errors. Please advise. Here is the latest/greatest code: http://artichokemedia.com/macaw/

Comment: would love to hear any feedback

Comment: No, sorry if I was not clear, I think you misunderstood me. Change `$('js/jquery.sidr.min.js').ready(function() {` back to `$(document).ready(function() {`. I am going to take another look at your website.

Comment: Ah I see the problem. I will post the solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***STEP 1***

Since you're are trying to use a `Sidr` navigation implementation, and since  `Sidr` is a plugin, and reliant on `jQuery` you have to make sure to include the `jQuery` library before the `Sidr` plugin.

In your index.html simply change the order of your script tags.

What you have:

```
<script src="js/jquery.sidr.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-min.js"></script>
<script src="js/rimages.js"></script>
```

What you should have:

```
<script src="js/jquery-min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.sidr.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/rimages.js"></script>
```

This will resolve your errors.

***STEP 2***

It appears that your anchor tag is being placed behind the top div so we will need to change the `z-index` to bring it forward. Add the following to your `css` file.

```
.mobile-menu-trigger {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 33; //bring content forward
}
```

This brings the clickable menu button forward, of course you will need to do some additional styling, but the basic `sidr` navigation menu should now work.

Comment: Also, make sure to move this block of code: `<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#right-menu').sidr({
  name: 'sidr-right',
  side: 'right',
  });
  });
  </script>` to below the three script tags at the bottom of your `index.html`.

Comment: Well thanks for the help! I'm sure it did solve some code issues but I am not seeing any slideout menu. Onscreen there is no clickable button state for the slideout animation to occur. Any comments? I truly appreciate it